# Support Vector Machine (SVM) vs K-NN testing efficiency

Tags: c++, machine-learning, svm

If a Support Vector Machine (SVM) model is computed, when running the model against a test set, is it more efficient that running KNN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean calculation time or s.th. like accuracy with "efficiency".

if you want to know about how good your classifier is i would say it depends on your data. if there where a classifier which is "best for everything", wouldn't it be the only one used?

if you want to know about calculation speed then its a yes. K-NN compares your test-datapoint with all training-datapoints to classify it. SVM only needs its supportvectors so the testing here should be significantly faster.

Edit:

Like MSalters mentioned there are ways to improve the calculation speed of K-NN so the above statement might not be true for very good optimized algorithms, but for the basic concept it is.

Comment: Your K-NN implementation is a bit naive. Theoretically, you indeed determine the nearest neighbor by calculating all distances and minimizing the distance. In practice, pre-processing the set is a viable option especially when the K-NN has many points (i.e. when it matters).

Comment: Yes you are right and there is also the worst case for a svm that all vectors become support vectors. So it can also depend on your data. But an out of the box knn is usually slower than an out of the box svm.